# 1 А класс / 1 "А" класс

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, наращение

Отпала ли в сочетаниях, таких как *1 А класс*, *2 Б класс*,  необходимость использовать кавычки, как и в *на ты*, например? И нужно ли наращение?

Answer (score 6):

Кажется странным, что такое, всем известное с детства, словосочетание не кодифицировано. Приведу только [информацию с сайта «Грамота.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87):

> **Как писать названия классов: 1а класс или 1-й «А» класс?**
>
> Специальных правил оформления литеры в названии класса нет. В прочих случаях литерные добавления, как правило, пишутся строчными буквами без кавычек и присоединяются без пробела и без дефиса к предшествующей цифре: *рисунок 1а, пункт 2д, дом 3а* и т. д. Поэтому по аналогии можно было бы написать *1а класс, класс 10г*, но на практике такой вариант не используется.
>
> Наиболее распространены варианты оформления с прописной литерой, заключенной в кавычки: *наш 10-й «Б», поступил в 1-й «А» класс* и т. д. Такое оформление особенно уместно в тех случаях, когда литера располагается не сразу после числительного (или когда числительное вообще отсутствует): *10-й класс «Б»; классы «А» и «Б»*.
>
> При написании числительного словом используется аналогичное оформление: *первый «А» класс, десятый «Б»*. Ср.: *Здесь можно было переждать какую-нибудь опасность, покурить, поговорить с девчонкой – словом, свой **девятый «В»** Мельников не случайно обнаружил именно здесь.* Г. Полонский, Доживем до понедельника. *Служкин запустил **девятый «А»** в кабинет и раскрыл классный журнал.* А. Иванов, Географ глобус пропил.

Comment: В поддержку ответа: *Тогда его спасла историчка Фаина Израилевна Фурманова, классрук **10-го «Б»**.  ...вспоминала выпускников 1951 года, тот самый **десятый «Б»**, где учились и Вознесенский с Тарковским* (И. Н. Вирабов. Андрей Вознесенский). *Прочтя на доске такие исключительно свободные темы сочинений, **10-й "Б"** не удивился: это было в знакомом стиле Марины Максимовны* (Георгий Полонский. Ключ без права передачи).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо, Римма!